# Weird error with windows cmd using git after using git diff

Tags: git, cmd

This is the first time I've ever encountered this bug, when I'm using cmd or gitbash on windows and I use the command `git diff` then `ctrl + c` to exit, I wouldn't be able to type any more commands afterwards because typing `g` would do something weird, as if I'm writing in a file, have a look:

[image]

**Note** this only happens after I use `git diff` and close it off, my guess is it doesn't close off properly.
The only way to fix this for me is to close off the window and start a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if that persists with the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

Second, check if using 'q' instead of CTRL+C works better.

Comment: using q doesn't produce the problem